# Sql Server Agent REPL Jobs

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

I know that replication uses Sql Agent jobs to pull subscriptions. Are these jobs supposed to stay in an 'executing' state? (Sql 2008 SP1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replication agents run as jobs scheduled under the SQL Server Agent.  They can be scheduled to run continuously or on a recurring schedule.

If the replication has been scheduled to run continuously, then yes, it could be continuously 'executing'.